# Need help in Restricting php file upload type to pdf and doc, docx

Tags: php, html, pdf

i know its a already asked question only, I have referred those questions no solution has been found from them so am posting my own question sorry guys

I have a PHP attachments from where it sends the attachment to my email, in that I have restricted the file type to accept only pdf and doc but its not working correctly and also i have restricted the file size that also not working, I will post my php and HTML codes here please correct me if am wrong thanks in advance

**HTML Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Ajax Contact Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
    <div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
    <div id="contact_results"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="form-control"/>
        </label>

    </div>
       <div class="form-group">
              <label><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="form-control"/>
        </label>
       </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label><span>Phone <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="form-control" />
        </label>  

     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label><span>Attachment</span>
            <input type="file" accept="doc,pdf,docx" required="true" name="file_attach" class="form-control" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

   <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />

        </label>

      </div>
      </div>
</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "m.balajivaishnav@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
    // $from_email  = "noreply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com"; //From email address (eg: no-reply@YOUR-DOMAIN.com)

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
       if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\n\n".$user_name."\nEmail : ".$user_email."\nPhone Number :". $phone_number ;

    ### Attachment Preparation ###
    $file_attached = false;
    if(isset($_FILES['file_attach'])) //check uploaded file
    {
        //get file details we need
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['file_attach']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['file_attach']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['file_attach']['error'];

        //exit script and output error if we encounter any
        if($file_error>0)
        {
            $mymsg = array( 
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 

            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output); 
        }

        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        //now we know we have the file for attachment, set $file_attached to true

     $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
         echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
      else
      {

$file_attached = true;  
      }
  }

    }

    if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
    {
        $boundary = md5("sanwebe"); 

        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$user_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$user_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body)); 

        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 

    }else{
        //proceed with PHP email.
        $headers = "From:".$user_email."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $body = $message_body;
    }

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);


    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
```

I think, you mean:

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
```